# Пустой ответ в sql-запросе через PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo, like

Пытаюсь выполнить запрос через PDO, ответ пустой. Хотя сам по себе запрос корректный. Что я делаю не так?

```
$user = "Example";
...

$q = $db->prepare('
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE
    (user LIKE :User OR site LIKE :Site)
AND 
    (type LIKE :Type) 
ORDER BY date
DESC LIMIT :limit
OFFSET :offset
');

$q->execute(array(
':User' => $user . '%',
':Site' => $site . '%',
':Type' => $type . '%',
':limit' => $limit,
':offset' => $offset
));
```

Comment: `bindParam()` не подходит?

Comment: Отключите эмуляцию перед запросом, до вызова метода `prepere()`:  `$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );`. Тогда плейсхолдеры можно использовать для `LIMIT` и `OFFSET` без дополнительных действий

Comment: Также неясно что вы выводите и как.